# How can i replace %20 to space in a specific column?

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, sql-server-2016

I do have a table (fund) that has a column named 'fText'.
This table has around 700k data and some data randomly has some '%20' in middle of string. The Column type is `varchar(5000)`.

For example in one row, I have `'Today%20is%2010/3/2019%20%20'`.
The '%20' can be anywhere in `ftext` column. is there anyway to clean up all 700k data with `Update` statement?

I need a update statement that can change such text to below. (Replace all %20 to space ' ')

> Today is 10/3/2019

Comment: Check REPLACE(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi , I used `begin transaction;
update ff_fundinfo
set fundtext=replace(fundtext,'20%',' ') where fundtext like '%[%]20%'` But it did not work.

Comment: `replace(fundtext,'%20',' ')`

Comment: Ops, you are right :) thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@forpas helped me and II got this answer :)

Thank you

The answer:

```
begin transaction;
update ff_fundinfo
set fundtext=replace(fundtext,'%20',' ') where fundtext like '%[%]20%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this -

```
DECLARE @Sample VARCHAR(100)='Today%20is%2010/3/2019%20%20'
SELECT @Sample AS INPUT,LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@Sample,'%20',' ')))
```

For Scenario - Use this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Fund') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Fund

Create table #Fund 
(
ftext varchar(5000)
)

insert into #Fund(ftext) 
values 
('Today%20is%2010/3/2019%20%20')

--SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(ftext,'%20',' '))) FROM #Fund

UPDATE #Fund SET ftext=LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(ftext,'%20',' '))) WHERE ftext LIKE '%[%]20%'

SELECT ftext FROM #Fund
```